# Arc connectedness implies uncountability

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

We define a space X to be arc connected if $\forall x,y \in X$, with $x \neq y, \exists $ a continuous injective function p such that $p: ([0,1], standard) \rightarrow (X, \tau)$ with $p(0)=x, p(1)=y$.

However, why is it true that every non trivial arc connected topology is uncountable, I couldn't see the link between connectedness and countability.

Thanks!

Comment: Umm, $p$ is *injective* so...

Comment: You probably mean the *topological space* is uncountable, not the *topology*, which is the set of open subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an injection namely $p$ between an uncountable set $[0,1]$ and a subset of $X$. This means $X$ is uncountable.